# Typography, typographer ... typograph?

Tags: single-word-requests

The words *typography* (the craft of designing the appearance of printed text) and *typographer* (one who designs the appearance of printed text) are well-known in English.  Both have the form of derivations from a hypothetical base verb, **typograph*, but that word is vanishingly rare. ([Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=typograph%2C+typography%2C+typographer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctypograph%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctypography%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctypographer%3B%2Cc0) shows it nearly 10x rarer than *typographer*, itself 7-10x rarer than *typography*; [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/typograph) lists the word only as a technical term for letterpress printing; [etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=typograph) doesn't show it at all.)  It seems to be a genuine lexical gap.

Given that, what would you suggest one use as the verb with the meaning "to design the appearance of printed text"?  (I am aware of *text design* but this is rare outside the publishing industry, and has a slightly different denotation there; people employed as "text designers" may or not consider themselves to be "typographers.")

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence where this verb would be called for?  (Off the cuff, I'd be inclined not to use a 'custom' verb, but to say 'doing typography' or perhaps 'lay out' instead.)

Answer (score 1):

Especially when talking about older printing methods, you can use ***[to typeset](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/typeset)*** (*“to set or compose written material into type”*) or ***[to compose](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compose)*** (*“To arrange (types) in a composing stick for printing”*).

For modern typography, ***to design*** is often used.

Comment: _Compose_ is also commonly used, and as a verb, so is simply _set_.

Comment: @Janus presumably *set* is directly equivalent to *typeset* or *set type*.

Comment: While *typeset* probably is the most appropriate verb (+1), a typesetter's job is to apply the designs of a typographer to a piece of work. *Typographer* as a font designer couldn't be covered by typeset

Comment: @ChrisH Yes, exactly. _Typeset_ is more specific and thus works better with less context; but in context, in my experience, _set_ is more common. For instance, if someone asks you what you do at work and you reply, “My main work is securing image rights, but I do quite a lot of setting too”, most people would probably not know immediately what kind of ‘setting’ you were referring to; but if you work for a publisher as a typesetter, your editor colleague is more likely to ask you, “Have you set that text on moth mating rituals yet?” than “Have you typeset that text on moth mating rituals yet?”.

Comment: @ChrisH (In reply to your second comment) That depends on the workplace, essentially. In a large workplace with very narrowly defined job descriptions, a typesetter may be someone who gets a text design and simply sets text to match the layout he sees. I’d venture it doesn’t work like that _most_ places, though. When I set books, I decide on the visual layout of the book, including text design (composition) and graphic appearance in general. As a general rule, I don’t think type designers consider themselves typographers—at least I’ve never heard a type designer refer to himself as one.

Comment: @Janus (i) I use *set* myself that way in a LaTeX context so I know what you mean. (ii) I'll happily defer to your expertise (I based my comment on my understanding of old-fashioned typesetting); hopefully the discussion helps the OP/reader when considering the nuances of usage.